# PySpark Create a new lag() column from an existing column and fillna with existing column value

Tags: pyspark, pyspark-pandas

I am looking to convert my Pandas code to PySpark and create a new column with the existing one by grouping the data on 'session' and shifting data to get the next row value for 'next_timestamp'.
But for the last row in every group, I am getting null value and I was able to overcome this in pandas by filling NA with existing column value. Need to achieve the same in PySpark.

Below is the expected output:

```py
| session | timestamp | next\_timestamp |
| ------- | --------- | --------------- |
| 1       | 100       | 101             |
| 1       | 101       | 102             |
| 1       | 102       | 103             |
| 1       | 103       | 104             |
| 1       | 104       | 105             |
| 1       | 105       | 106             |
| 1       | 106       | 107             |
| 1       | 107       | 107             |
| 2       | 108       | 109             |
| 2       | 109       | 110             |
| 2       | 110       | 111             |
| 2       | 111       | 112             |
| 2       | 112       | 112             |
| 3       | 113       | 114             |
| 3       | 114       | 115             |
| 3       | 115       | 116             |
| 3       | 116       | 117             |
| 3       | 117       | 118             |
| 3       | 118       | 118             |
```

Below is the output that I am currently getting:

Code

```
df = df.withColumn('next_timestamp', lag('timestamp', -1, 0).over(Window.partitionBy('sessionId').orderBy('timestamp')))
```

Output

```py
| session | timestamp | next\_timestamp |
| ------- | --------- | --------------- |
| 1       | 100       | 101             |
| 1       | 101       | 102             |
| 1       | 102       | 103             |
| 1       | 103       | 104             |
| 1       | 104       | 105             |
| 1       | 105       | 106             |
| 1       | 106       | 107             |
| 1       | 107       |                 |
| 2       | 108       | 109             |
| 2       | 109       | 110             |
| 2       | 110       | 111             |
| 2       | 111       | 112             |
| 2       | 112       |                 |
| 3       | 113       | 114             |
| 3       | 114       | 115             |
| 3       | 115       | 116             |
| 3       | 116       | 117             |
| 3       | 117       | 118             |
| 3       | 118       |                 |
```

I was able to achieve the expected output in pandas with the below logic

```
df['next_timestamp'] = df['timestamp'].groupby(df['sessionId']).shift(-1).fillna(df['timestamp'])
```

Need to convert the same in PySpark and fill NA with either ffill() or col['timestamp'] from that row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think a simple `when-otherwise` transformation should do the job:

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, when

df.withColumn("next_timestamp", when(col("next_timestamp").isNotNull(), col("next_timestamp")).otherwise(col("timestamp")))

| session | timestamp | next_timestamp |
| ------- | --------- | --------------- |
| 1       | 100       | 101             |
| 1       | 101       | 102             |
| 1       | 102       | 103             |
| 1       | 103       | 104             |
| 1       | 104       | 105             |
| 1       | 105       | 106             |
| 1       | 106       | 107             |
| 1       | 107       | 107             |
| 2       | 108       | 109             |
| 2       | 109       | 110             |
| 2       | 110       | 111             |
| 2       | 111       | 112             |
| 2       | 112       | 112             |
| 3       | 113       | 114             |
| 3       | 114       | 115             |
| 3       | 115       | 116             |
| 3       | 116       | 117             |
| 3       | 117       | 118             |
| 3       | 118       | 118             |
```